# strace reports bad file descriptor

Tags: linux, bash, system-calls, strace

Trying to debug my program which doesn't return to the bash prompt, I used `strace` and gave it the PID. The program is a binary file and I don't have the source code. According to the `strace`, there is a `-1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)`. However, I don't know which file is problematic.

As you can see below the `strace` exits, so running `lsof -p <PID>` has no result.

```
read(5, "80\0\0\0\00078", 8)            = 8
read(5, "prf-exit\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 80) = 80
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2af316b0f000
write(1, "\n", 1)                       = 1
read(5, "\0\0\0\0", 4)                  = 4
write(5, "\0\0\0\0", 4)                 = 4
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 9
setsockopt(9, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
setsockopt(9, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0
setsockopt(9, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [65536], 4) = 0
setsockopt(9, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, [65536], 4) = 0
fcntl(9, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl(9, F_SETFL, O_RDWR)               = 0
connect(9, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(45323), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.10.10.251")}, 16) = 0
write(9, "12345\0", 6)                  = 6
write(9, "15  NORMAL_EXITING\0", 19)    = 19
read(9, "\0", 1)                        = 1
close(9)                                = 0
futex(0x2af31686d9d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 29590, NULL) = 0
futex(0x2af31666c9d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 29589, NULL) = 0
close(6)                                = 0
close(7)                                = 0
read(5, "\0\0\0\0", 4)                  = 4
write(5, "\0\0\0\0", 4)                 = 4
read(5, "\0\0\0\0", 4)                  = 4
write(5, "\0\0\0\0", 4)                 = 4
close(5)                                = 0
close(5)                                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 5
connect(5, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(49986), sin_addr=inet_addr("172.20.54.10")}, 16) = 0
setsockopt(5, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
setsockopt(5, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0
write(5, "\35\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 64) = 64
close(5)                                = 0
close(4)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
Process 29588 detached
[root@compute-0-3 ~]# lsof -p 29588
[root@compute-0-3 ~]#
```

How can I search for the missing/erroneous file?

Comment: This isn't necessarily a bug. If you want to be sure a FD is closed, there's no good reason to make sure it's open first -- you can just try to close it and ignore the EBADF if you get one.

Comment: ...if you're using Python's `close_fds` flag when starting a subprocess, for instance, it'll just run through FD numbers 3-255 and try to close all of them, no matter whether they're open or not.

Comment: BTW, consider using sysdig instead of strace -- among other things, you can ask it to dump the FD table of a process (any process -- it's system-wide monitoring) *as it existed in the past, at any point in time*.

Comment: Also, since `exit_group(0)` was called, the program is explicitly reporting a *non-erroneous* status. If this is how something reports it's exiting with an error, that's... unusual, to say the least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're closing the same file descriptor twice:

```
close(5)                                = 0
close(5)                                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
```

Comment: Hi @Andrew , sorry for asking relatively irrelavent question. Does -1 stands for EBADF? In `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h`, 1 stands for EPERM. Also in [source code of Strace](https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/master/src/linux/generic/errnoent.h), it also states that 1 is EPERM. How could Strace states that a syscall retval of -1 stands for EBADF error instead of EPERM? I do believe that the syscall here tries to imply "bad fd", but I can't figure why Strace uses -1 instead of -9 (EBADF in the abovementioned files) to represent the failure. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`EBADF` happens when a file descriptor number isn't mapped to a file. Thus, by definition, there **is** no file that's problematic.

---

Frankly, this isn't a bug, and certainly isn't the bug you're looking for. It's entirely common behavior to try to close FDs even if you're not sure they were open to begin with -- it's more efficient to do so than to try to check for whether a file descriptor is still open via other means and close it only conditionally.

Comment: *FD 5 was formerly mapped to a socket connected to `10.10.10.251`.*  How did you conclude that?

Comment: By a misreading, frankly -- on closer look that was FD 9. Retracting it.

Answer (score 2):

Closing a file descriptor more than once is a very bad idea if your program is multi-threaded, because after you close it for the first time, another thread can call open() and be given the same file descriptor (but referring to a different file); at which point calling close for a second time in your thread will close the other thread's file. Always use something like:

close(x);
  x = -1;

to make sure you don't inadvertently close a reused descriptor.

Comment: And even that is not thread-safe, right?